# finding all continuous functions $f$ so that $f(f(x)) - 2f(x) + x = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, continuity, contest-math, functional-equations

[image]

> I have some questions about the solution below, which appear after the solution.

[image]
[image]

> Why can we assume that $\Delta f(a)$ and $\Delta f(b)$ are positive? If I directly plug in $g(x) = f(x) + c$ into the equation instead of f, I get $f(f(x)+c) + c)- f(x)-c = f(x)+c - x$, which may or may not hold because of the $f(f(x)+c)$ term.

> Why is $\Delta f(f^{(m-1)}(b)) > \Delta f(a)$? I tried using a similar argument to what they discussed in the solutions but I still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think that "adding a constant" means replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x+d).$ For $d$  large enough, we have $f(a+d)-a>0$ and $f(b+d)-b>0$ because it can be shown (by contradiction) that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty.$